# How does one switch PhD advisors without being on a fellowship?

Tags: phd

What's the best way to switch PhD advisors/or get a taste for working with a potential advisor without being on a fellowship?

In other words how would I convince a potential advisor to fund me + avoid burning bridges with my current advisor?

Let's say the reason for the switch is that I realized I'm not that interested in the research area my advisor is focused on now.

Comment: Do you have a good relationship with your current advisor? Is he likely to be supportive of this, or will he actively work against you on this?

Comment: Relationship is good.

Comment: What year of PhD are you?Usually in the first year there should be no problem, some PhD programs include in 1st year a round of 3 supervisions in order to chose a suitable direction.

Comment: How are you being funded?

Comment: The question lacks too many details that are relevant to give proper answer. Like the scheme of how the department finances PhD students, etc.